# How to take content from two same nodes separately?

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have HTML file with list of product names and prices

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span class="name">Name 1</span>
      <span class="price">3.99</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span class="name">Name 2</span>
      <span class="price">5.49</span>
    </label>
  </li>
...
</ul>
```

and need to take names and prices from each `<label>` separately.
I'm using Nokogiri to parse HTML file and tried

```
file.xpath('//ul/li/label').each do |item|
  puts item.content
end
```

but, as you may have guessed, it returns both name and price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name and price `span` elements are children of the `label` element, so you can fetch them using `xpath` within the scope of each `label`

```rb
file.xpath('//ul/li/label').each do |item|
  name = item.at_xpath("span[@class='name']").text()
  price = item.at_xpath("span[@class='price']").text()
  puts "#{name} - #{price}"
end
```

or using css selector

```rb
file.xpath('//ul/li/label').each do |item|
  name = item.at_css('.name').text()
  price = item.at_css('.price').text()
  puts "#{name} - #{price}"
end
```

Comment: It'd be clearer to use `css('label')` instead of `xpath('//ul/li/label')`, or at least switch to `xpath('//label')`. In general, CSS selectors are easier to read than XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I'd use something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span class="name">Name 1</span>
      <span class="price">3.99</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span class="name">Name 2</span>
      <span class="price">5.49</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
EOT

data = doc.css('label').map { |label| [label.at('.name').text, label.at('.price').text] }.to_h 
# => {"Name 1"=>"3.99", "Name 2"=>"5.49"}
```

As long as the `.name` text is unique, which it seems like it should from the example HTML, the resulting hash will be valid and easy to use.

*IF* you need them in order then Ruby will return the key/value pairs in the order they're originally inserted if you iterate over them, which is not something I recommend relying on because in other languages you can't rely on that but your mileage might vary. Otherwise, the lookup to retrieve the value for a given key is extremely fast, no matter how many entries there are because it's a hash. And, a hash can be passed around for a lot of useful munging.